# Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer on real algebraic bundles on $P_3(C)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

See [ADHM original paper](http://inspirehep.net/record/134505?ln=en),

In [ref. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5oAG.png) Proc.Roy.Soc.Lond. A362 (1978) 425-461_Selfduality in Four-Dimensional Riemannian Geometry by M F Atiyah, Nigel J Hitchin, I M Singer](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinlist/Atiyah%20Hitchin%20Singer%20Self-duality%20in%20four-dimensional%20Riemannian%20geometry%20(PRSTL%20A%201978).pdf),

it was shown that “instantons”, i.e. self- dual solutions of the Yang—Mills equations in the compactified euclidean 4-space $S^4$ corresponded in a precise way to certain real algebraic bundles on the complex projective 3-space $P_3(C)$.

Since some people uses the different convention for the complex projective 3-space $P_3(C)$ (like [this post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/), but why to use this different convention?), say the $P_3(C)$ as the 4-dimensional real-space instead of  6-dimensional real-space manifold, I would like to make sure:

> 1. In ADHM and in this Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer paper, the notation $P_3(C)$ is a 4-manifold, or 6-manifold for the real dimensions?
> 2. If it is the case, why do one construct the real algebraic bundles on the complex projective 3-space $P_3(C)$ (4-dim or 6-dim manifold in the real space?) to realize an instanton solution in 4-space?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in that blog that uses a different convention. $\Bbb CP^n$ (my preferred notation for your $P_n(\Bbb C)$) always means the complex manifold of complex dimension $n$, and thus real dimension $2n$. Perhaps you refer to when Qiaochu writes that $X$ has real dimension $2n-2$, but $X$ is not $\Bbb{CP}^n$, it is a hypersurface inside that space (which has complex codimension 1 = real codimension 2).

An unrelated confusion often arises if someone writes something like $\Bbb P(\Bbb C^n)$; this would mean the *projectivization* of the vector space $\Bbb C^n$, and projectivization lowers dimension by 1; so $\Bbb P(\Bbb C^n) = \Bbb{CP}^{n-1}$.

---

The twistor construction identifies (theorem 5.2) self-dual Hermitian connections on a bundle $E$ over a 4-manifold with self-dual curvature (note that these are two different concepts, one involving the curvature of a connection, and one involving the *Weyl tensor* of a Riemannian 4-manifold) with holomorphic bundles over an associated complex 3-manifold equipped with an antiholomorphic automorphism.

This is useful because it is usually *very hard* to explicitly construct self-dual connections, much less identify the entire moduli space thereof. Of course, the ADHM construction does this very beautifully and explicitly for $S^4$ (or $\Bbb R^4$, depending on your taste), but this is pretty much one of the only cases where this is possible.

It is nice, in particular, that one can apply this result to Einstein manifolds. I don't know off the top of my head anywhere this is applied, but I am sure one can find it around in the literature.

Comment: +1, thanks, in Qiaochu Yuan blog, he wrote that "In (complex) hypersurfaces in \mathbb{CP}^n. When n = 3 the resulting complex surfaces give nice examples of 4-manifolds", but I thought we need \mathbb{CP}^2 as $\mathbb{CP}^2$ to have a  4-manifolds for n=2 instead of n=3.

Comment: I understood your point. So what is that hypersurface in Qiaochu blog precisely?

Comment: @wonderich (I am not sure if this was clear or not, sorry if  I 
am repeating something you know)  The point I wanted to make in the first paragraph was that taking a hypersurface decreases complex dimension by 1, so real 4-manifolds (complex surfaces) arise as hypersurfaces in $\Bbb{CP}^3$, which has complex dimension 3.

Comment: That I knew, I am wondering are there many different hypersurfaces, or is that just a particular hypersurface in this Qiaochu construction.

Comment: It is the zero set of a polynomial $F$. As long as that determinant of a matrix of derivatives he mentions is nonzero, the resulting smooth manifold only depends up to diffeomorphism on the degree of $F$ (and of course the dimension of the ambient projective space). He writes this as a theorem early in the post, and proceeds to just refer to it as a hypersurface of degree $d$.

Comment: For the 2nd subquestion, I do not see an answer yet.

Comment: I initially didn't notice the second question (sorry), but the point is just that algebraic geometry is much easier to do than constructing solutions to the ASD equations. If you are asking what the construction is, I suggest reading the original paper.

Comment: ASD equation? you mean AHS or ADHM above Refs?

Comment: Anti-Self-Dual. It's equivalent to the self dual equation on $M$ with the opposite orientation. The mathematical literature has settled on this as the preferred convention, due to the more direct relationship with holomorphic bundles over Kahler manifolds, so this is the name I usually think about. Saying that instead of self-dual was a slip of the tongue.

Comment: Thanks so much!